# Proving that function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have $f$ - $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable complex function in some domain $D$ and $F$-differentiable real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ if $Re f(z)=F(Im f(z))$ in $D$ then  $f$ is constant
I don’t know how to attempt this problem. I tried to use Cauchy-Riemann conditions but I didn’t get needed result

Comment: Do you know that the image of a non-constant holomorphic function is an *open set?* Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis).

Comment: Uhm, I heard about it but still I can’t get your hint. How it can be helpful

Comment: If the image is contained in $\{ x+iy \mid x = F(y) \}$ – can it be an open set in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Generally it isn’t. Sorry can’t get this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a non-constant holomorphic function then $f(D)$ is an *open set,* according to the [Open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Now choose an arbitrary  $z_0 \in D$. Then  $u_0 + i v_0 = f(z_0)$ is an interior point of $f(D)$. In particular, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
 \{ (u_0 + t) + i v_0| -\epsilon <  t < \epsilon \} \subset f(D) \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 u_0 + t = F(v_0) \quad \text{for all $t \in (-\epsilon , \epsilon)$}
$$
which is not possible. Therefore $f$ is necessarily constant.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: $u_0+t=Re (f(z))=F(\Im f(z))$ for some $z \in D$. How does that give $u_0+t=F(v_0)$? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: $u_0 + t + i v_0 = f(z)$ for some $z \in D$ implies $u_0 + t = \operatorname{Re}(f(z)) = F(\operatorname{Im}(f(z))) = F(v_0)$. Did I make an error?

Comment: I see that $\Im f(z_0)=v_0$ but I don't understand why $\Im f(z)=v_0$ for all $z \in D$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Take the imaginary part on both sides of  $(u_0 + t) + i v_0 = f(z)$. Note that $u_0, t, v_0 $ are all real numbers.

Comment: Very sorry for not seeing such a simple point. +1 for  your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a:=f'(z_0)\ne 0$ for some $z_0\in D$.
Then $f(z)-f(z_0)-a\cdot (z-z_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$.
In particular, letting $z=z_0+it\overline a$ with $t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, we find that 
$\Im f(z)>\Im f(z_0)$ for small positive $t$ (say, for $t=\frac1n$ with $n\gg 0$) and $\Im f(z)<\Im f(z_0)$ for absolutely small negative $t$ (say, for $t=-\frac1n$ with $n\gg0$). Hence on *any* path within $D$ leading from $z_0-\frac1n i\overline a$ to  $z_0+\frac1n i\overline a$, there is a point $z_n$ with $\Im f(z_n)=\Im f(z_0)$.
By choosing a nice path, we can easily ensure that $0<|z_n-z_0|<\frac1n|a|$.
By the given condition, also $\Re f(z_n)=\Re f(z_0)$, i.e., $f(z_n)=f(z_0)$ for all $n\gg 0$. As $z_n\to z_0$, we find that $0\ne a=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(_n)-f(z_0)}{z_n-z_0}=0$, contradiction.

Note that we did not even use the smoothness of $F$. :)